# How to map 3 or 4 FirebaseListObservable using common $key value?

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

I have three node in Firebase database, I want to join there three different object in to single one `firebaseListObservable` and render into html using `*ngFor` list derivative, so I don't know it's possible or what is best way to join this nosql data using rxjs. I am new to reactive programming to haven't knowledge how to combine all object into one.

Database structure as like this:

```
live_markets : {
  id(45789) : {
   type : "NUF",
   openPrice : 465.45,
   closePrice : 789.89,
   ....
  },
  id(78982), id(57455)... 
}


market_description : {
 id(45789): {
  name: "Abc Comapny",
  expire : "08/07/2017",
  symbol : "ABCS17AY",
  ...
 },
 id(78982), id(46447)...
}

users : {
   uid(Kd234w3423fd435): {
     profile : {...},
     watchList : {
      45789 : true,
      78982 : true,
      57455 : true,
   },
   uid ...
}
```

There are three FirebaseListObservable and i successfully  map two but can't all in to one.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-market',
  templateUrl: './market.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./market.component.scss']
})
export class MarketComponent implements OnInit {

  liveMarket: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  //market_description: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

   const watchlist$: FirebaseObjectObservable<any> = db.object('users/Kd234w3423fd435/watchList');
   watchlist$.map((Keys) => {
     return  db.object('/market/' + `${Keys.$value}`);
   }).subscribe( (items) => {
      this.liveMarket = items;
   });


  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

It works well, but how to join (map) market_description KEY  with this.liveMarket using user/uid/watchList KEYS, what is the proper method?

Comment: db.object('/live_markets /' + `${Keys.$value}`); sorry it is typing mistake when i asking question it is live_markets  not market

Comment: If you wish to correct something in your post, [please edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46012964/edit).